# Wordpress contact form 7 send confirmation message to user

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to send confirmation message to user after submitting form.

the information recorded should be sent to client & confirmation message send to user.

Is there any setting in contact form 7 or we need to do it using custom ?

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 9):

Ya you can send confirmation email to user.
Just use Mail 2 option which will be triggered only when the email is successfully sent to client.
https://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-implement-autoresponder/

Comment: This isn't recommended anymore by WPCF7 since It could be misused by an intruder to Send Spam emails from your Email Address. 
https://contactform7.com/configuration-errors/unsafe-email-without-protection/

Comment: @MichaelSchober that depends, as now a days emails will not reach the mailbox unless its sent through SMTP with proper credentials or oAuth.

And by chance if somebody wants to send spam emails then its not necessary that mail2 will give a easy way out to do that as that can be done with a normal php mail or by direct CF7 also and which is difficult now a days as spam filters at the mailbox end are much stronger to verify un authorized emails.

+1 for updating about the recent recommendation from CF7

Answer (score 0):

You can use contact 7 forms for it but you may have to then hardcode where is it going. So if you go onto the page the form is on you will see

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

If you change this code to something along the lines of

```
<input type="submit" href="example@example.com"/>
```

When clicked it should then send the required data to the correct e-mail address. Make sure that your form has the method of "POST" so the data actually gets sent over.

Also with contact form 7 there is an option to do e-mail forms, you can then set the e-mail to your e-mail for testing and your clients e-mail too. Send some dummy data over and job should be a good'n. Just look at the different options you have available.

This link should help you below:
https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/